# Apache Beam Python Unit Testing a ParDo class with_outputs

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a ParDo class that checks if a pubsub message contains certain attributes and returns a valid and invalid TaggedOutput (that works fine in the normal flow, using yield for returning the values), and I am not able to do unit testing for this class, I am trying to provide a dummy message (dictionary replicating pubsub message info) and I want to check if the output of the class contains other attributes.

this is what I have so far:

```
class TestValidateMessage(unittest.TestCase):

def test_not_valid(self):
    with TestPipeline() as p:
        pcoll = (
                p
                | beam.Create([{'attributes':{"imageUrl":000}}])
                | beam.ParDo(ValidateMessage()).with_outputs(
        'invalid', main='valid'))
    valid, _ = pcoll
    invalid = pcoll['invalid']
    print(invalid)
    assert_that(invalid, {'failure_step':'Message validation'})
```

With this I get an error message:

```
TypeError: Map can be used only with callable objects. Received {'failure_step'} instead.
```

When I try to print(invalid), I get `PCollection[ParDo(ValidateMessage)/ParDo(ValidateMessage).invalid]`
How do I access (for asserting purposes) the content of the PCollection?

Answer (score 4):

TLDR;

This piece of code has three problems:

- The assert_that() is executed *after* you run the pipeline.
- You must use equal_to(), is_empty(), or is_not_empty() as a condition in assert_that()
- At the end of the pipeline, you'll get an array. Test always against [ expected_result ].

Corrected code:

```
class TestValidateMessage(unittest.TestCase):

def test_not_valid(self):
    with TestPipeline() as p:
        pcoll = (
                p
                | beam.Create([{'attributes':{"imageUrl":000}}])
                | beam.ParDo(ValidateMessage()).with_outputs(
        'invalid', main='valid'))

        assert_that(pcoll.invalid, 
                    equal_to([ {'failure_step':'Message validation'} ] )
```

## Long explanation

In Apache Beam, you have to test the code *inside* the pipeline.

Beam does the assertion for you building a pipeline from a PCollection.
Looks complicated but it is simpler as it looks.

If you have a pipeline like that:

```
with TestPipeline() as p:
   pcoll = p | Beam.Create( testdata ) | Beam.DoFn(I_Want_To_Test_This())
```

You must add the assert_that *inside* the with clause, since assert_that() will add code to do the assertion inside the pipeline.

```
with TestPipeline() as p:
   pcoll = p | Beam.Create( testdata ) | Beam.ParDo(I_Want_To_Test_This_DoFn())
   assert_that(pcoll, equal_to(expected_data) )
```

This is the same as doing this:

```
P = TestPipeline()
pcoll = p | Beam.Create( testdata ) | Beam.ParDo(I_Want_To_Test_This_DoFn())
assert_that(pcoll, equal_to(expected_data) )
p.run()  # Test must be run _inside_ the pipeline
```

When you have multiple outputs it is similar:

```
with TestPipeline() as p:
   pcoll = (
       p 
       | Beam.Create( testdata ) 
       | Beam.ParDo(I_Want_To_Test_This_DoFn()).with_outputs('valid','invalid')
   )

   # You can test inside the pipeline with assert_that

   assert_that(pcoll.invalid, equal_to( [ {'failure step':'Message validation'} ] ))
```

Maybe you want to check the other outputs are empty:

```
from apache_beam.testing.util import assert_that, equal_to, is_empty, is_not_empty

...

with TestPipeline() as p:
   pcoll = (
       p 
       | Beam.Create( testdata ) 
       | Beam.ParDo(I_Want_To_Test_This_DoFn()).with_outputs('valid','invalid')
   )

   # You can test inside the pipeline with assert_that

   assert_that(pcoll.valid, is_empty() ), label='valid')

   assert_that(pcoll.invalid, equal_to( [ {'failure step':'Message validation'} ] ), label='invalid')
```

In that case, you'll need to add a label to the assert_that() just to make sure it is able to generate the correct pipeline.